# Self-promoting book

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

I'm a regular answerer (for the async/await questions, at least) on SO.

I've recently finished writing a book: O'Reilly's Concurrency in C# Cookbook. As you may guess, a lot of the recipes would apply to the async/await questions that I regularly answer on SO.

So, the question: is it acceptable for me to mention the applicable recipe in an answer? [This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23549221/263693); the answer stands alone (it's the preferred solution), but the recipe would also be useful (also covers an alternate solution, with more discussion).

Would a link be acceptable? Of course, I'm certainly not going to get rich by self-promoting on SO (technical books tend to lose money overall, especially in a narrow target market). OTOH, that feels like pretty blatant self-promotion.

So I ask the community: should I remove the mention of the book at all, leave it as-is, or add a link?

Comment: There's already a lot of [discussion on this topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=promotion) already...have you looked through any of that yet?

Comment: Ah, apparently I was only searching meta.stackoverflow.com, not meta.stackexchange.com. I was wondering why this wasn't covered!

Comment: Skeet, Lippert (maybe more) somehow find a way to let people know they have published without using answers.

Comment: See my answer to [What signifies good self promotion or self promotion part infinity?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182237/) for a possible inspiration/example.

Comment: @GarryVass: It's not a matter of using an answer as a way to let people know that I've published a book - but I *do* use answers as a way of referring to more information. So long as the answers are helpful in and of themselves, I don't think it's a bad thing to point to more information, even if it's only available after purchase.

Comment: Self-promotion only bothers me when it is not explicitly clear that you are doing it, or the answer suffers for a lack of complete detail unless you call now (operators are standing by!) I know others feel strongly about this in different directions, but I only take exception when paid content is offered with feigned objectivity and masked intentions, or when it is shoehorned into an answer awkwardly as a blatant web traffic honeypot. If you simply mention that you wrote a book on a subject that you're answering on, that works for me; I can click your profile and get a link if I want more.

Comment: It's always at least partly self-promotion because it is not a neutral selection of sources. So if done too often it'll get annoying. I would restrict the mentioning of the book. Don't do it too often. However I like that you clearly say that it's your book.

Comment: Small print footnotes in answers might be nice too. After all the reference to the book does not answer the question directly but rather refers to more information.

Comment: Stephen, debate about the ethics of promotion aside, congratulations on the book :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I can't believe you're promoting your own post like that! ;-)

Comment: @Caleb: Well, at least we don't have to pay actual money to read Josh's shamelessly self-promoted post!

Comment: What? Your bill is in the mail already, @JohnY.

Comment: I prefer it this way: If it is publicly accessible source and it answers the question clearly, just link to the source is sufficient for me. But if it is not public (like, need to purchase a book), a good answer+reference to the source for more details is best, because everyone may not be able to buy the book to get the answer. In short, main point is whether question is answered (without spending money for that). For those who want to learn more than the answer, may be, let them pay. And example in question is good way to do it, I feel.

Comment: I did not know you had a book Stephen. Now that I do though.. I will be purchasing it :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: My master plan worked! Subtle self-promotion by *asking* about self-promotion! Mwa, ha, ha!

Comment: I address this very issue in my book...

Answer (score 42):

I think as long as the answer is useful, self-contained and stands on its own it is fine to refer to an outside source for more information even if that information is behind a *pay-wall* so to speak.

Further I think it might be quite helpful to the person asking if they were anyways looking for more resources on whatever the topic area of their question was. Especially considering that when it comes to tech books the largest cost is usually not the price of the book but rather the time it takes to read the book. An answer from the author of the book can be a great indicator of whether their book would be worth your time.

Comment: "...if they were anyways looking for more resources..." - asking for off-site resources is explicitly off-topic because such questions "tend to attract spam".

Comment: That's correct, but we aren't talking about the OP asking for off-site resource just that they (or someone else that finds the answer) might be looking for more information on the subject (or even if they weren't they might find it useful now that it was pointed out to them).

Comment: I agree with this part ONLY if the answer stands on its own and the pay-wall outside source is a way to get additional information (not talking about non-paywall outside sources). I do, however, think that information should be separated somehow. Either in a comment or a new section for "additional sources". I say this because I have had answers to my own questions where the answer contained no real effort to answer the problem, but suggested paying money for a solution instead. This is essentially offering the outside paid source as the solution itself.

Comment: @Jack . . . I agree strongly, which as an author is obviously self interest on my part.  A corollary is that encouraging authors to contribute to Stack Overflow should benefit the community overall.  I don't think every answer should be a reference to a book, but on rare occasions, I don't hesitate to make the reference.  (If anyone actually looks through my answers and comments, they will see that I really do mean very rarely -- perhaps once every three months.)

Answer (score 38):

> I cover this in more detail in recipe 2.6 of my Concurrency in C# Cookbook.

I don't think that helps answer the question. Since I can't access that information unless I buy the book (or unless you link to an online version of that chapter), mentioning the book only serves to promote it. I think you should either add a link to the content (not just to a place to buy the book) or remove the reference.

Comment: I don't know - I'd view it as neutral for those who don't have the book (and don't want to get it), and positive for those who do have the book. It's linking information which may not be obvious even to those with the book - what's the *harm* of including it? It's important that the answer itself gives enough information to be useful stand-alone, but I don't see that it's a bad idea to give extra information as well.

Comment: (And it's not just for my own book, of course - I'd be very happy to refer to specific items in Effective Java, for example...)

Comment: @Bill By that same logic, shouldn't *all* [links to Amazon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links) be removed?

Comment: @JonSkeet It doesn't give extra information though. It just says that the information exists somewhere else without linking to it or including it.

Comment: @StephenCleary Are *all* links to Amazon only promoting a book without quoting the relevant information?

Comment: @Bill: Saying where the information is (which recipe) is information in itself.

Comment: @Jon It's not useful information though. It's like linking to a site that's behind a paywall. It still doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @Bill: But that's why it's important that it's not the whole answer. It's just an extra *bit* of information in an otherwise standalone answer. And it *is* useful information to those who have the book. If you don't have the book, it does no harm and the rest of the answer is still fine. It is only additive, IMO.

Comment: And as Stephen pointed out, a link to a book us similarly just information behind a paywall. Does it matter whether the author of that information is also the author of the post? We always say that a post should be judged on its usefulness, not its author... Why would a post be *less* useful because of who posts it?

Comment: @Jon I'm not saying it's less useful because of who posted it. I'm saying the extra bit of information isn't useful at all. If the question is *completely* answered, then I don't need to look at the book, and the reference isn't necessary. If the question *isn't* completely answered, then it should be, and the book reference should be a link to the missing content.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I don't think it's nearly as black-and-white as that. Is there *any* answer which has absolutely everything that can possibly be said about it? I don't think so. Do you view every answer as "incomplete" then? And you keep saying it's not a link... it's not a hyperlink, but it provides as much information as you need to get to the extra information as an Amazon link would... more, in fact, as it tells you the exact place in the book. Yes, it would be more convenient if it were a hyperlink to Amazon to get the book, but I don't see that as a fundamental issue.

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is that either this is fine - could be better by being a hyperlink, but fundamentally okay - or we should look down on *every* book link. I don't view the fact that I'd have to (gosh!) copy and paste the book title into a search bar as something so egregious that it deserves castigation, nor do I view the fact that the post author is also the book author as relevant... and the latter is what Stephen was mostly concerned about, I suspect.

Comment: @Jon You've put quite a few words in my mouth that I never said. I'm not arguing in favor of authors linking to Amazon. I'm arguing in favor of linking to freely-available content, or including all the relevant information in the answer, as we have always strived for. I'm not castigating anyone, but I do think it makes a difference if the author of a book is promoting their work vs. someone else leaving a link as a citation reference.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I've been trying to understand your perspective. What you haven't explained is what you want to happen if there is paid-for content which (either for reasons of copyright or expediency) *will* not be included in the answer. Is it better to provide a reference to that content or not? My view is that it is *only* beneficial - it does no harm to those who aren't going to follow it up, and makes it easier to find the content for those who want to. I think we need to accept "some content is non-free" as a fact of life, and work out the best way of handling it.

Comment: @Jon I think I have already explained that. A reference to a book or a link to a site behind a paywall does not answer the question. I think it would do harm to the site if we let authors promote their books instead of answering questions. (I don't think that's what's happening in Stephen's case, so I think we've strayed slightly off-topic.)

Comment: I was never suggesting the link should take the place of a real answer. I was talking about cases like this specific one, where there's already a perfectly reasonable answer which no-one would view as "incomplete" in itself. Does it give every scrap of information possible about the topic? No, but neither does pretty much any answer. So is the link to more (non-free) information helpful, harmful or neither? My view is that it's helpful to some, harmful to none, and therefore okay.

Comment: @Jon If the answer is complete, then the reference would appear to only be there for self-promotion. I'm not saying it's actively harmful in this case, just that it really doesn't need to be there. It seems to serve the author's own purpose more than anyone else's. (Maybe I've spent too many years moderating, but I really can't seem to develop a taste for self-promotion in answers at all. It's just my opinion. Since the community seems divided on this, I'm not taking any action.)

Comment: Again, that assumes a black and white view of "complete" vs "incomplete". Would you view any answer which didn't contain every scrap of information that the answerer could provide as incomplete? If I only answered questions when I had time to do a full brain dump, I'd rarely post anything.

Comment: @Jon "complete" vs "incomplete" isn't about the answerer, it's about the question. Just because you have more information doesn't mean that it's required.

Comment: I think some of it also comes down to the *"teach a man to fish..."*, in that even with a complete self contained answer it still good/nice to provide pointers to additional information to user.

Comment: @Jack Sure, if that information is made freely available, including a reference to it should be encouraged. The question is what utility it serves when that's not the case.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think it serves the same basic utility, in that it can potentially help someone reading the answer find a good place to get more information. The only difference is that in this case it will cost them, but if they aren't interested in paying they don't need to since the answer itself is self contained.

Comment: So basically the question is: "I gave a usefull answer, is it ok to now shamelessly self-promote my book?"

Comment: @user3008011 Yes, that is basically how I'm reading the question. While I will agree with Jon that this case isn't quite that black-and-white, I do view the quoted reference as about 10% helpful, 90% promotional.

Comment: Is the issue *shameless self promotion* or that whats being promoted costs money, because if the issue is *"shameless self promotion"* than that applies even if the content is *"freely available"*.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: More information may not be *required*, but it can be useful - even if it's *not* freely available.

Comment: I have come out strongly against paywall content, promotional robots, and all ends of monetizing your time on SO. I think it is unethical for certain users to monetize what the rest of us are giving away -- slippery slope to ExpertsExchange. That said, if a **complete** answer mentions that even more detail is available in a book which the answerer wrote and is left at that, I can click your profile and follow the link if I want it. Speaking as an admitted jerk about the issue, that doesn't raise my hackles a bit.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it can be useful to people who are willing to pay for it, or who have already paid for it. That's the issue. The author is trying to get people to buy their book. That's not what we're here for.

Comment: @Chris so you are saying that you would be ok with author mentioning that they cover it in *even more* detail in their book but you object to them adding where in the book (what section/page)?

Comment: By that logic, Can I end my answers with: "Here's an answer, for more detail here's my bank account details?" :P

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I don't view it as "the author is trying to get people to buy their book" - I view it as "if you've already got my book, you'll find more information here". That's certainly what I intend when *I* leave similar chapter references.

Comment: @Jon The title of the question is "Self-promoting book."

Comment: @BilltheLizard You don't have to buy a book just to benefit from it. Your local library is a fantastic and under appreciated resource.

Comment: @Caleb That really doesn't change my mind at all. Knowing that there's more information in a book in the library doesn't help me solve my immediate problem. I can search Google and Amazon (or even my library's card catalog) if I'm looking for a book.

Comment: @Jack I guess it really depends on the phrasing and context. If you say, "As I discuss in-depth in my book *I Don't Actually Have a Book*...", fine if a little smarmy. You mentioned the book, now I know, but it doesn't read like you've left out information and hit me over the head with a plug for where I can pay you to get it. Now if I want more info, I can seek it out. Stackoverflow does sell ads. When you get into page/chapter specifics, when you're dedicating a section of your answer to a plug, I think you've crossed the line.

Comment: I think a good metric is whether you'd say it in a conversation. It would be insufferably pretentious to mention chapter and page references to your own book in a conversation, but not the simple fact that you have a book.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think we all agree that the answer has to be self-contained without the information from the book, in other words it needs to contain the information to "solve your immediate problem".

Comment: @Chris it probably would be *insufferably pretentious* to mention it in conversation, but then you also wouldn't give a detailed line by line code example in conversation either.

Comment: @Jack Yes, that's well-established. If the answer is already self-contained, then a plug for the author's book is more self-promotional than helpful to the reader.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Hopefully the rest of the answer solves your immediate problem. But a book citation might lead you to a more in-depth answer than one could reasonably put in an answer on SO, and many people wait days or longer for a decent answer -- traveling a few blocks or miles to a local library isn't an undue burden. And Google, Amazon, or the card catalog aren't always great solutions for searching content.

Comment: @Chris If people are going to be allowed to promote their book anyway, I'd rather they be as specific as possible. If they're citing a specific chapter and section, it's more likely to actually be useful than if they just recommend their entire book on a general topic.

Comment: @Caleb If I'm looking for a more in-depth answer than one could reasonably put in an answer on SO, then my question is off-topic and I *should* be searching for a book, not waiting for days or longer for an answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: This is the black-or-white completeness thing again. What I believe Jon and Caleb (and others) are saying is that there's often a "sufficient" answer to a question. It helps. It's good enough. But there's usually more information that would be *useful* to bring up. Perhaps further detail than is appropriate for the Stack Exchange format; perhaps more rationale; perhaps something that shows the asker "when you get more advanced, you can use this *even better* way to accomplish your goal"; etc. An answer can give the asker a fish, *and* provide a link showing them how to fish.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I don't see it that way, but it isn't up to me. Simply mentioning the book signals "I have level 9001 knowledge on this subject" without being overtly promotional; it is able to be casually inserted into a sentence or paragraph which goes on to deliver the meat of the answer. A full citation to the book is less about establishing expertise and more of a signpost/advertisement for the book and its content. It is an effective paywal -- you're "linking" to content that must be paid for.

Comment: Another consideration: when you have a book to promote and link to, does that not create a disincentive to link to freely available information which accomplishes the same "teach a man to fish" aim that is being claimed as the altruistic motive for referencing the book? If your aim is simply to teach, surely there are free resources which can be linked to without any potential for controversy or questions of conflicting interest.

Comment: I think the title of this blog post sums up this conversation well: http://blog.codinghorror.com/programmers-dont-read-books-but-you-should/

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I may not have purchased the book (yet), but I may have access to the book through other means. A colleague may own it. My team may own a copy of the book. Or I could use a service like Safari Books Online. If the book is in their collection, then I can read it right now (since I pay for the full library).

Comment: @JonSkeet Using Bill's example, what is the difference to saying "That topic is covered in the manual"? Why would I not link to that content or nab some quotes from it (properly credited of course) that would contribute to the answer. The statement in Bill's example alone provides no immediately beneficial content. I could see something like "As I said in my Concurrency in C# Cookbook 'the pony drinks water from the pond'" If I was asking where the pony gets his water, this answer would provide some actual benefit to the answer. IE, make the promotion add real benefit to the answer.

Comment: @Tom: You do realize that Bill's example is only at the *end* of an answer? The post itself answers the question - this is just referring to more detail. The "promotion" already adds real benefit by saying where there's more information available. It can often be tricky to know which *aspect* of "more detail" would be most relevant, and it's reasonable to assume that the existing answer text is already covered in the book... so in some ways you could think of the answer as alreayd being "As I said in my Concurrency in C# Cookbook: [... rest of answer...]". It's just the link is at the end.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that there are two important aspects to this question:

- Is it okay to cite books in answers?
- When, if ever, is it okay for an author to cite his or her *own* book in an answer?

**On the first part:** We tell people: ["If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) But it's often easy to see that an entire book or a chapter would help an OP, and I don't think there's anything wrong with pointing someone to a book as an additional resource, provided that the reference doesn't substitute for a useful answer to the OP's particular question.

You don't have to buy a book in order to learn from it -- most communities in the US have a library, and even if the library doesn't have the book in question, it may be able to procure it for you through inter-library loan. The information in many books is also available in other ways, e.g. though paid services like [Safari](http://www.safaribooksonline.com), sometimes on free sites like [Google Books](http://books.google.com), and portions may be available through previews. (I was able to preview the OP's book and see [the section he referred to](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9781491906675/2dot-async-basics/recipe_async_orderbycompletion_html) at no charge.)

**On the second part:** This comes down to motivation. You shouldn't mention your book if your goal is to *promote* it, even if it will only increase sales by 1 or 2 units. On the other hand, if you're honestly trying to add a useful resource to your answer, it doesn't matter whether you're the author or just a happy reader. That's a fine line, and it's hard for readers to judge someone else's motivation, so perhaps a more practical standard is *relevancy*. If your citation is relevant to the OP's question, then a citation is probably fine.

Additionally, if you're quoting from a book directly or indirectly, you *should* cite the book whether you're the author or not.

> Would a link be acceptable? Of course, I'm certainly not going to get
>   rich by self-promoting on SO... OTOH, that feels like pretty blatant
>   self-promotion.

Go with that feeling. If *you* feel like it's blatant self-promotion, then it probably is. Don't try to figure out how you can work a reference to your book into an answer so that you can sell more books. Put a link to your book in your profile instead, so that people who go looking for more information about you will find it. Nevertheless, I think there are times when an author might reasonably refer to his or her own work without necessarily *promoting* it.

Comment: One possible way to judge motivation is how often one does it and how partial (not refering to other books) one is. Relevancy also seems difficult. If the question is self-contained then relevancy of further information is somewhere in the middle, difficult to judge really. How often is further information really needed? It might just be overkill.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you could make some useful parts of your book that you think you would use in many of your answers publicly available, sort of as teaser excerpts (except they don't leave you wondering :P). Then, you could provide links to those parts when you answer a question in which it applies, and people who find your excerpts helpful may consider buying the book for more.

Just an idea that came to me, not anything from experience, but I hope it helps in some way!

Comment: I think that is what he is actually doing: Making the most relevant part of his book public in the answer, and refer to the source for more.

Answer (score 5):

I've read the lengthy discussion between Bill, Jon and others. I know how you feel. I've written a book myself, and regularly answer questions that would be answered by the book. Although my answers are self-contained, the book would lead to much much deeper insight.

> should I remove the mention of the book at all, leave it as-is, or add a link?

If the content is publicly available, then by all means add a link. If it's behind a paywall then don't mention it at all.

By not mentioning the book + chapter + page it feels like I'm letting the OP down. Because I give the man a fish instead of teaching him how to fish. It feels like I'm holding back. But consider the perspective of the readers of your answer. Many readers probably come to Stack Overflow for quick solutions, and the obvious self-promotion is a turn-off, and waste of time to even read that sentence mentioning your book.

> Of course, I'm certainly not going to get rich by self-promoting on SO

Exactly. So the reference won't help *you* in any way. It won't lead to increased sales, and it won't win you a popularity contest. Yes, a keen reader could gain in-depth knowledge by reading your book, but they will be a tiny tiny minority. The vast majority will not appreciate it.

Spare yourself the drama. Just don't bring it up. You'll sleep better. Your profile is the perfect place to put this stuff, people who like your answer and want more of your wisdom will go there, and will be more receptive to the idea of investing in your book.

Answer (score 3):

The way I solve this is that I've posted the content of my book online as a set of XHTML Web pages; plus I've put all the code examples from the book as actual Xcode projects, along with all the figures, as a Github repository.

Then when I answer a question, I actually give the answer, which might include code pasted in from the book; and in a subsidiary *comment* I might provide a link to an example or to the relevant section of a Web page. That way, I'm providing something of immediate value, and the answer itself is not dependent on the link (which, after all, could become outdated).

My technique has evolved over time. I used to include links in the answer, but linkrot has taught me not to do that. And I used to describe these resources as "from my book", but now I no longer do that either; I just say in my comment "I explain further here" or "Here's an actual downloadable example", and I let people discover that these are connected with a book if they are so inclined. They might discover this from my bio at Stack Overflow, or from the header on the Web pages or the Read Me at Github.

But if they don't, I don't care. My goal is to help people, not to advertise the book. I fought hard with O'Reilly for the right to post the book's content online for free, and I'm glad I did; those pages get a lot of hits, and my Github repository has a lot of stars.

At *no* time do I *ever* say, "You'd know more about this if you bought and read my book." Though, to be sure, I'm probably thinking it! Actually I'm usually thinking "How could you not have googled and found my book / examples online, since they tell you exactly what you need to know?!" But the point is, I use *available* and *completely free* content, with no strings attached, to supplement my efforts to provide answers and to educate people.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for posting a link to the book, especially when answering a newbie's question. You'are already doing a tremendously great job and free community service here with your answers. Most of them have been fairly self-contained and targeting the questions to their cores, at least, to my memory.

So, people are already receiving an adequate help, sufficient to solve their problems. Plus, any follow-ups in the comments. If the asking person *is willing to learn more* on top of that, he/she should spare a few bucks and get the book, the money will be well spent in this case. If he doesn't, it's his choice to ignore the link.

Whether it will turn into a sensible profit for you is hard to predict. Apparently, newcomers are lazy to learn by reading books... why bother if there's a place like SO?

Anyhow, well done on the book. I really wish I had something like this a year ago, when I started using TPL and `async/await` extensively, but it reads great now, too. Here you go: a meta-promotion! :)

Answer (score -3):

Let us assume the answer is only available in his book for simplification.

If the author would not answer here, the answer would not be available on the internet. It is much harder to find informaton in a paper based book wihthout knowing which, and that it exists at all. 
So, for most practical purposes, that means it is "just not available".

Now, in answering the question, he makes part of the book available for free, and perfectly easy find.
But while the part he makes availab is only a small fraction of the content,
he selects the fraction that provides **100% of the actual problem solving value** to the asking user.

So, one could argue that, for the asker, the **monetary value of the answer** is at least as large as the full price of the book.
That is because the only way to solve the problem without the anwer has the cost of the sum of the cost of the following parts:

- decide to risk literature research effort, not knowing a suitable book exists
- conduct literature research, including recognizing a book can solve the problem without access to the text
- aquire book at full book price or from library
- recognize section of book or repeat from top
- adapt solution from book to actual problem

I expect the sum of costs (including backtracking loops) is greater than the full book price.

When, realistically, but contrary to the simplifying assumption, his answer is not the only possible, but merely the best answer - or even just one of multiple good answers, it would change the details, but I feel the argument would still apply.

When looking from this viewpoint, it is perfectly acceptable when the author of both the answer and the book adds a reference to his book.
The form of the reference could describe it from this viewpoint, like below:

*(This answer is an excerpt from my book "Answering Interesting Questions Every Day", section 3.1.4 "Answering: example 2345" adapted to your problem (ISBN99999999))*

Comment: Actually, from intuition, I do agree with the other answers just as much; But when I found this perspective, it seemed like well worth writing it down.