# What does the "Tenacious" badge mean?

Tags: support, badges, accepted-answer

The description of the [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) badge reads:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

My translation: *You have more than 5 accepted answers that have zero upvotes, and this is 20% of the total number of your accepted answers.*

1. Is my translation correct?
2. Why is this a badge? (What's notable about it, and why should I care?)

Comment: @devnull: As far as I can tell, this question hasn't been asked _here_. It has been asked at [meta.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69322/262755, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99742/262755, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60886/262755 (among some others).

Comment: @unit3524344 is correct. It is listed on meta.stackexchange.com but not here. (Sorry for my lack of knowledge about the separate sites, I wasn't aware of the separate metas.)

Comment: @Bill: Generally speaking, you don't need to know about the other metas.

Comment: See the second comment after the question in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254062/self-promoting-book). Apparently I'm not the only one who did not know about meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, you need at least 6 answers that are accepted and still at 0 *when they are at least 10 days old*. They need to make up at least 20% of all your accepted answers (over 10 days old).

The badge exists to encourage answering in less-popular tags, where you may get a lot of questions from new users that cannot yet vote.

There is a gold version of the badge too, [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero), requiring more than 10 0-score accepted answers and 25% of the total.

Comment: Nice to find out about this 10 day threshold.

Comment: Even harder are the tags (or the very old questions) where you don't even get the answers accepted. To address that pattern, I proposed a [gold badge for the revival/necromancer pattern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268), **Persephone**.

Comment: @Nemo: that's a very complete and thorough proposal.

Comment: Emm, so why do [I have the Tenacious badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious?userid=5236226)? User ID: 5236226, Query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i

Comment: @CalebKleveter the SEDE data set is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning. Later that day [one more answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40407087) qualified but the query won't reflect this.

Comment: as a programmer, I'm embarrassed to say that I did not catch that 5 is not more than 5 in this case...

Comment: Is it awarded when you have a answer out of the six that got upvoted and then downvoted back to 0 or the other way around or both?

Comment: @zixuan: it doesn't matter. The score of a post is not dependent on the order of the votes.

Comment: How do you tell whether 0 upvotes indicate the OP is unable to vote or the answer is not good enough? Isn't it common for upvotes to come from others searching for answers?

Comment: @OldGeezer: the operative term here is 'less popular tags', so the number of people with the rep to vote searching for answers in those tags is going to be lower.