# Are answers to my own questions (self-answers) counted for Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges?

Tags: support, badges

The descriptions for the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges are:

> **Tenacious**: Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.
>
> ---
>
> **Unsung Hero**: Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

These descriptions do not explicitly say whether accepted answers that are self-answered are counted towards these badges. This isn't specified in the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/262588) to the Meta Stack Exchange question [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/262588) either.

If they are, that would defeat the purpose of the badges: to [encourage answering questions on low traffic tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261691/1461424).

So, are my own answers counted towards the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges?

Comment: No. "Community wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations." from the MSE FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

They don't count, according to [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834/295232) by a former Stack Overflow employee:

> - Only accepted answers older than 10 days are considered (otherwise tons of new users would get this)
> - As long as they are not self accept

This is also reflected in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange, which is pretty reliable when it comes to badges.

> Community wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations