# Why haven't I received the Tenacious badge?

Tags: support, badges

These are the requirements of the tenacious badge:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total

I didn't understand what's the meaning of this, and then I came [across this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261691/9819031)

When I check my 0 score accepted answers by taking help from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312224/9819031), I see that I have 10 total accepted answers and 6 of them have 0 scrore.

And most importantly they all are 10 days old. What does this mean? Have I not completed the requirements for this tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only have five accepted answers that are zero-scored, because one of them is self-accepted and does not count towards the badge.

Comment: Okay that's what I missed thanks for pointing out. Already the badge has conditions difficult to achieve and again can't count self-accepted answer.

Comment: @Gourav: This badge is not meant to be “achieved”, it’s a consolation price for not getting upvotes. :D

Comment: That too is correct:)

Comment: I still have a question: if my answer gets upvote after 10 days; will it still be counted for the badge?

Comment: @Gourav No. It only looks at what the score is at the time the badge check runs.