# Answer with book recommendation valid?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, self-promotion

I recently stumbled over an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47768154/4763309) that was answered on the one hand technically to the question, but at the end of his answer he recommended one of his written books with a link to it, so you can eventually purchase it.

Should this answer actually marked as spam or is this valid to promote his own publications as part of an answer?

Comment: I read your linked answer, but in my case the promoted link does not provide more information directly, only after purchasing the book.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254062/self-promoting-book) is more relevant but it was closed as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. I used the wrong search terns, otherwise I would also have found it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks fine to me.

- it is a real answer
- he doesn't sign all (or any other) of his answers with the book link
- the book is relevant to the topic discussed
- there is full disclosure about the relationship between him and the book

In general, if you are going to flag for improper product promotion or spam, it is good to check whether or not that user is just answering with a link or single simple sentence, is signing every single answer with a link to their product, is not disclosing the relationship to the product, or is linking to the product when it has absolutely nothing to do with the topic.

As this post meets none of these, it really isn't harming anything, and should be left in place.

Comment: Alright thank you for your detailed answer :) So next time I encounter such an answer I will check some of the authors other answers too to build an opinion.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic - Yeah, that is a good place to start. That is probably the path a mod would take to if a post like that was flagged. I think they may or may not have some internal tools available for spam related to that type of content depending on escalation. In this case though, I think once the other posts are considered, and the overall approach that user takes, a mod would decline such a flag on that post. If, next time, you start to look around and it is clearly adding up on each post, that is certainly enough reason to flag.